# Как прижать футер к низу окна браузера?

Tags: html, css

Примеров полно, но нет ни одного, чтоб с пояснением.

Comment: - [Как прижать подвал к низу экрана?](http://www.websovet.com/kak-prizhat-podval-k-nizu-ekrana)
- [Как прижать футер (footer, подвал) к низу экрана?](http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/html/div-verstka-html/blochnaya-verstka-div-verstka-kak-prizhat-footer-k-nizhnej-chasti-ekrana-maket-sajta-blochnoj-verstki.html)
- [Как прижать подвал к низу страницы?](http://www.zakharov.ms/footer/) Поиск по словам: как прижать подвал. Все примеры с пояснениями на русском.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```css
* {margin: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
.wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -97px; /* margin-bottom должен быть отрицательным со значением height у .footer, .push */
}
.footer, .push {height: 97px;} /* значение должно равняться margin-bottom у .wrapper (положительное число) */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <!-- CONTENT -->    
     <div class="push"><!-- NO CONTENT --></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
     <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

Comment: @Vadizar скажите, чем лучше стал ответ от вашей правки? Вроде бы ничем. Если хотите принести пользу — оберните код в сниппет, этого здесь действительно не хватает.

Comment: @NickVolynkin просто код без какого-либо комментария пугает людей. Я считаю неверным и думаю, вы согласитесь, оставлять полотно кода без комментариев. P.S. Обернул в сниппет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате и я объясню вам свою позицию и мы решим, стоит ли так делать или нет.

Answer (score 1):

[Генератор HTML+CSS шаблонов](http://csstemplater.com/) - вот здесь возьмите, создайте шаблон, там есть функция прижатия футера. А там дальше вытащите из кода.

Comment: спасибо, но мне результат не так интересен,мне понять хочетса

Comment: Если посмотреть на результат, то понять не сложно.

Comment: Там очень много всего непонятного, пытаюсь понять, но не могу.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование для фиксированной высоты футера

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   content
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

#### 2. Решение через Flexbox для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  /* Чтобы занимал оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
  /* Чтобы footer не уменьшался */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 3. Решение через таблицы для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: table-row;
  /* Чтобы ряд занимал всё оставшееся пространство, так как табличная разметка не позволит ему вытолкнуть header и footer */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 4. Решение с использованием jQuery для адаптивной высоты футера

```js
// Высчитываем высоту footer и делаем соответствующий отступ от main:
function footer(){
$('main').css('padding-bottom',$('footer').height());
}
window.addEventListener('load',footer);
window.addEventListener('resize',footer);
```

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer по умолчанию */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer по умолчанию */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```