# Прижать футер к низу страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток, вопрос заезженный. В гугле есть информация , но во всех примерах нужно оборачивать ненужным div блоком. подскажите пожалуйста можно ли обойтись без него. Например есть вот такая вот структура

```
<header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt sequi</p>
</header>
<main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. taque cupiditate quas quasi soluta.</p>
</footer>
```

можно ли как то сдесь прижать футер, не оборачивая его ? в див лишний, спасибо

Comment: ответ есть тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33753/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: там обертывают wrapper , основной контент, а в моем вопросе следующее можно ли оставить так чтобы не Обертывать в лишний div

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? Это 1 див. 1!!! При генерации дерева на реакте, целостной страницы, их может быть от 5к и более. И странице это не особо мешает. Так что экономить на таких вещах, совсем не обязательно. А по теме: примеров в интернете куча, используйте любой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - через `position: absolute;`:

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: А действительно, что за негативные оценки? Звучит очень практично и легко, при том что и работает как просят.

Comment: @Levelleor потому что бред написан. При таком раскладе футер будет наезжать на основной контент, если он достает до низу экрана.

Comment: @Vadizar отступ внизу? :) Ну то есть метод-то рабочий и ним вполне можно пользоваться, даже если метод выше выглядит правильнее.

Comment: @Levelleor он не рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

На случай, когда нет возможности использовать дополнительную оберку, но нужно железобетонное решение я написал эту функцию на `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).on('ready', stickyFooter);
$(window).on('resize', stickyFooter);
function stickyFooter() {
    var $footer = $('.footer');
    $footer.siblings('.spacer').remove();
    var contentHeight = $('body').height(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height();
    if(contentHeight < windowHeight) {
        $footer.before('<div class="spacer" style="height: ' + (windowHeight - contentHeight) + 'px;"></div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Не силен в джейкверри , как применить к разметке которую я выit указывал ?

Comment: Вместо .footer писать footer

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование для фиксированной высоты футера

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   content
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

#### 2. Решение через Flexbox для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  /* Чтобы занимал оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
  /* Чтобы footer не уменьшался */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 3. Решение через таблицы для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: table-row;
  /* Чтобы ряд занимал всё оставшееся пространство, так как табличная разметка не позволит ему вытолкнуть header и footer */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 4. Решение с использованием jQuery для адаптивной высоты футера

```js
// Высчитываем высоту footer и делаем соответствующий отступ от main:
function footer(){
$('main').css('padding-bottom',$('footer').height());
}
window.addEventListener('load',footer);
window.addEventListener('resize',footer);
```

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer по умолчанию */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer по умолчанию */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```