# Как можно прижать футер когда мало контента в данном случае и футер вложен в правый блок?

Tags: css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно прижать футер когда мало контента в данном случае и футер вложен в правый блок?
[ссылка на мой макет](http://test3.dtraduga.vh66.hosterby.com/news.php)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Прижать футер к низу страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508287/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.wrp {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">Навигация
  </div>
  <div class="wrp">Контент
    <div class="footer">Футер
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```